# Convert Array to Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I like to convert a single array into a multidimensional array. This is what I get have web scraping a page, except it is not the end result that I am looking for.

**Change:**

```
Rooms: Array (
  [0] => name 
  [1] => value 
  [2] => size
  [3] => &nbsp;
  [4] => name 
  [5] => value 
  [6] => size
  [7] => &nbsp;    
  [8] => name 
  [9] => value 
  [10] => size
  [11] => &nbsp;
  [12] => name 
  [13] => value 
  [14] => size
  [15] => &nbsp;
)
```

Into:

```
Rooms: Array (
  Room: Array (
    [0] => name 
    [1] => value 
    [2] => size
  ),
  Room: Array (
    [0] => name 
    [1] => value 
    [2] => size
  ),
  Room: Array (
    [0] => name 
    [1] => value 
    [2] => size
  )
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First use [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to get rid of the `&nbsp;` nodes:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($x) { return trim($x) != '&nbsp;'; });

// Or if your PHP is older than 5.3
$array = array_filter($array, create_function('$x', 'return trim($x) != "&nbsp;";'));
```

Then use [`array_chunk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split the array into chunks of 3:

```
$array = array_chunk($array, 3);
```

This of course assumes you will always and only get tuples containing `name`, `value` and `size`, in that order.